# Min-max scaling on DCT coefficients

Tags: normalization, dct, rescale

If I do DCT on an input value with pixel range [-128, 127], next how do I min-max scale this DCT transformed output? What should be my maximum and minimum DCT values that I can use to find the [0,1] range re-scaled DCT coefficients?

```
rescaled dct = (dct - 
dct.min())/(dct.max()-dct.min())
```

I have looked at pixel value equivalents

```
 pixel.min()=0 and pixel.max()=255 are the rescaling values for pixel domain rescaling.
```